# Find $\lim\limits _{x\rightarrow \infty }\sin \left( x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-explanation

The original question is:

*Find each of the following limits or indicate that it does no exist even in the infinite sense.*

*(c)  $\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty }\sin \left( x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$*

I believe that this limit does not exist, but I am uncertain about how to prove it. Can someone provide a proof or explanation for why this limit does not exist as x approaches infinity?

Comment: Why do you think the limit does not exist? Does the limit of $x \mapsto \sin(x)$ exist?

Comment: Solve quadratic equations to find $x_{2n} \to \infty$ with $\sin(x_{2n}+\frac{1}{x_{2n}}) = 1$ and $x_{2n+1} \to \infty$ with$ \sin(x_{2n+1}+\frac{1}{x_{2n+1}}) =-1$.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Doesn't sin(x) oscillates between -1 and 1 as x increases therefore  the limit of x↦sin(x) does not exist?

Comment: The standard answer of my textbook said "As x→∞, x+1/x→∞, limsin(x+1/x) does not exist (see limsin(x))" but I feel like this proof is too blurred for me......

Comment: I am not talking about lim∣sin(x+1/x)-sin(x)∣, by the way.

Comment: This is not a proof, but rather a intuitive way to realise what is going on. ```https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oa3v0rhgpm```. If you scroll to the far right(or left), you can see that it just looks like a sine wave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $x=2\pi n$ for some large integer $n$:

then $\sin \left( x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=\sin \left(2\pi n+\dfrac{1}{2\pi n}\right)=\sin \left(\dfrac{1}{2\pi n}\right) < \dfrac{1}{2\pi n}$

and you can make this as close to $0$ as you like by taking $n$ large enough.

Now take $x=2\pi m +\frac\pi2$ for some large integer $m$:
then $\sin \left( x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=\sin \left(2\pi m+\frac\pi2+\dfrac{1}{2\pi m+\frac\pi2}\right)=\cos \left(\dfrac{1}{2\pi m +\frac\pi2}\right) > 1-\frac12 \left(\dfrac{1}{2\pi m +\frac\pi2}\right)^2$

and you can make this as close to $1$ as you like by taking $m$ large enough.

So you do not get convergence.

---

Plotting part of the curve, you can see when $x$ is large that it is close to $\sin(x)$ - shown in pink - which also does not converge, when $x$ is closer to $0$ that it cycles increasingly faster, and when $x=\pm1$ that there are turning points which unusually are not at the extreme values of $\pm 1$ even though all the other turning points are.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the sum angle identities and triangle inequality, we have
\begin{align}
\left|\sin(x)-\sin\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| 
&= \left|\sin(x)-\sin(x)\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\cos(x)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| \\[2pt] 
&\leq |\sin(x)|\left|1-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|+\left|\cos(x)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|.
\end{align}
Now take $\epsilon>0$ small enough so that $|\sin(y)|\leq \frac{1}{4}$ and $|1-\cos(y)|<\frac{1}{4}$ whenever $|y|\leq \epsilon$.

Finally, consider the function at points $x_n=\pi/2+n\pi$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ large enough so that $x_n\geq 1/\epsilon$. If $n$ is even, then
$$
|\sin(x_n)-\sin(x_n+1/x_n)|=|1-\sin(x_n+1/x_n)| \leq \frac{1}{2},
$$
while if $n$ is odd, then
$$
|\sin(x_n)-\sin(x_n+1/x_n)|=|-1-\sin(x_n+1/x_n)| \leq \frac{1}{2}.
$$